# How does one have multiple modal forms on a page using jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to have multiple buttons each popping up a different modal form using jQuery UI. Is this possible? How?

Comment: Can you post your markup? E.g. where does each form come from?

Comment: Are you sure you know what 'modal' means?

Comment: I think the OP simply means that different elements launch different modals.

Comment: @Paul C: No, not at the same time. Just a different one for different buttons.
@sje397: [This](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/modal-form.html) is what I and jQuery UI people mean by modal.
@Paul A: Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks!

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought 'at the same time' as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Just give your dialog elements different id's.

Example:

*html*:

```
<div id='d1' title='Hi1' style='display:none'>Hi from dialog 1</div>
<div id='d2' title='Hi2' style='display:none'>Hi from dialog 2</div>

<button id='b1'>Open dialog 1</button>
<button id='b2'>Open dialog 2</button>
```

*javascript* (on document ready event):

```
$('#b1').click(function() {
    $('#d1').dialog({modal: true});
});

$('#b2').click(function() {
    $('#d2').dialog({modal: true});
});
```